# Python PDF library

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation

What Python PDF libraries are there?

I need to make some PDF with many grids, and I'm looking for a library that allows to manage pages (multi-page). The library should calculate when the page is ended and then create the next page.

Comment: Maybe it could be rephrased to ask what libraries are suitable for generating appropriate PDFs for the askers use case. "The best" is too subjective.

Comment: With respect to your second "question" (pagebreaks) you might want to use `pdflatex`.

Comment: There is a nice tutorial, 

https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167

that named some 5 libraries:

pdfrw, slate, PDFQuery, PDFMiner, PyPDF2

Comment: [xhtml2pdf](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf) is based on html templates and uses ReportLab. It's quite fast to grab and it answers the OP needs.

Comment: There's also [rinohtype](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/), which is similar to LaTeX as it focuses on rendering structured documents. (full discloure: I am the author of rinohtype).

Comment: check the [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme) library. It's very powerful

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The two that come to mind are:

- [pyPdf2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2)
- [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html)

Comment: From reading pyPdf's documentation, it appears to manipulate existing PDFs. Is there a Python library that will print/convert to PDF? Thanks.

Comment: These libraries don't make PDFs. They just edit them.

Comment: Maybe, this Q&A can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python

Answer (score 33):

[Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/opensource/). There is an open source version, and a paid version which adds the Report Markup Language (an alternative method of defining your document).

Comment: Reportlab is really good.
Another good one for simple tasks and for people who know about html is xhtml2pdf.

Answer (score 5):

I already have used [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/opensource/) in one project.

Answer (score 3):

There is also http://appyframework.org/pod.html
which takes a LibreOffice or OpenOffice document as template and can generate pdf, rtf, odt ...
To generate pdf it requires a headless OOo on some server.
Documentation is concise but relatively complete. 
http://appyframework.org/podWritingTemplates.html
If you need advice, the author is rather helpful.