# Python PDF Libraries

Tags: python

I am looking for a good Python PDF library that would parse some format to pdf (I want to use it to programmatically create documents). I have dome some search, and PyPDF looks like an option. Is there any other libraries that I should be aware of?

Comment: This question has been asked so many times. Please search before asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python PDF library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413441/python-pdf-library)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read pdf file in python without converting it in unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097871/how-to-read-pdf-file-in-python-without-converting-it-in-unix)

Comment: check [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme) library. It's very powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few options: [`ReportLab`](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Python-for-PDF-Generation/), [`PyX`](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/), and [`pyfpdf`](http://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/).