# how to read pdf file in python without converting it in unix?

Tags: python, pdf

```
pdfile=open("tutorial.pdf","r")
xyz= pdfile.readlines()
pqr=pdfile.readline()
for a in xyz:
    print a
```

this code doesnot display actual content. Instead it displays some question marks and boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF files contain formatted data, you cannot read directly,

so use pypdf module!
click here https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/
Install and you can read without converting.

Answer (score 2):

A PDF file is not plain text - you can't just print its bytes to the terminal.  You'd need to use a PDF-reading library (see [Python PDF library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413441/python-pdf-library) for some suggestions) to read it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with textual PDF files, I would suggest using [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html).
(A complete example can be found here: https://github.com/syllabs/pdf2text)