# Python/Django - Can I create multiple pdf file-like objects, zip them and send as attachment?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to create a web app where some parameters are input and plots are created. I want to have a link which will be to download ALL the plots in a zip file. To do this, I am writing a view which will create all the plots (I've already written views that create each of the single plots and display them), then zip them up, saving the zip file as the response object.

One way I could do this is to create each plot, save it as a pdf file to disk, and then at the end, zip them all up as the response. However, I'd like to sidestep the saving to disk if that's possible?

Cheers.

Comment: You can use the python GZip library to zip in memory. But I am not sure if you can make the PDF in memory. you can also check out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413441/python-pdf-library) and xhtml2pdf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what worked for me, going by Krzysiek's suggestion of using `StringIO`. Here `canvas` is a `canvas` object created by matplotlib.

```
#Create the file-like objects from canvases
file_like_1 = StringIO.StringIO()
file_like_2 = StringIO.StringIO()
#... etc...
canvas_1.print_pdf(file_like_1)
canvas_2.print_pdf(file_like_2)
#...etc....

#NOW create the zipfile
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=all_plots.zip'

buff = StringIO.StringIO()
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(buff,'w',zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
archive.writestr('plot_1.pdf',file_like_1.getvalue())
archive.writestr('plot_2.pdf',file_like_2.getvalue())
#..etc...
archive.close()
buff.flush()
ret_zip = buff.getvalue()
buff.close()
response.write(ret_zip)
return response
```

The zipping part of all of this was taken from https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookDynamicZip

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) python module. It implements `file` behavior on in-memory strings.

Comment: All files are series of bytes (strings).