# Creating a PDF document with input from form

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, pdf

I am currently learning the django framework. Using django and bootstrap 3 I decided to create a customer database site for the company I work for. We fill out service tickets everyday so I wanted to make my life easy by writing them up on my phone and having it emailed to the customer (maybe implement jsignature at some point). 
The idea is to digitize our current paper service ticket. Place a form on the site, when it is submitted the information is placed inside the digitized service ticket, converted into a pdf, and emailed to select addresses.

My question is: What is the best way to create a template of the paper service ticket, how would I fill it in based on the information from the form and then convert to PDF so it can be emailed.

I did some research and found that I could create an html template, placed the information from the form into the designated blocks and use a library to convert html to pdf. Is this a solid method or is there a better way?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Html to pdf would work well.  One such as [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) would work well.  You could also create the pdf directly with a Python pdf library like [pyPDF or PDFMiner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413441/python-pdf-library)