# Python tool(s) to make drawings using dimensionful units

Tags: python, graphics

I'm going to make a camera calibration grid of dots ([like this one](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372916M-01/nivisionconcepts/spatial_calibration_concepts/)), and it seems like I
could do it almost trivially using `pyplot.scatter`, except that I want to be able to specify the locations and sizes of the dots in terms of centimeters.  I need to know the physical sizes and locations of the dots in order to do the camera calibration.

Is there a python module that allows one to programatically define a drawing, specifying distances in  terms of physical lengths (centimeters etc.), and allows exporting into a 
format that will print at the specified size (pdf maybe)?

So far neither `matplotlib` nor `svgfig` seem to provide dimensionful sizes.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413441/python-pdf-library) for Python tools for PDF creation - PDFs certainly use specific units (1/72 inches) but you can trivially convert to cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pyx](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/) works for me!  It has a `units` module so that

```
import pyx
pyx.unit.set(defaultunit="cm")
c=pyx.canvas.canvas()
c.fill(pyx.path.circle(1,2,0.25))
c.writePDFfile('filename')
```

draws a 0.25cm radius circle, 1cm to the right and 2cm above the origin (which is in the lower left hand corner of the page)