# How to write output data into pdf?

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I can't find a way how to write output data (lists or function return) into pdf in python. This is my simple code. I want to write the `i` of data list line by line in pdf. But the output shows only `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.
Which pdf module is would be better for me to use?

```
import fpdf

data=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

pdf = fpdf.FPDF(format='letter')
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)

for i in str(data):
    pdf.write(5,i)
pdf.output("testings.pdf")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating and writing to a pdf file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953770/creating-and-writing-to-a-pdf-file-in-python)

Comment: This works fine to me https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trml2pdf

Comment: Please see the solution on the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953770/creating-and-writing-to-a-pdf-file-in-python

Comment: nope. i want to write multiple dict files into pdf line by line!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing everything correct to write output into a PDF. But you are not getting the result you "want" because your *Python* code is not correct!

```
for i in str(data):
      .. do stuff with i here ..
```

does not do what you think it does. As soon as you convert `data` to a string, per `str(data)`, it magically *becomes* the string

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Then the `for` loop iterates over the contents of that string – its characters – and writes them one by one to the PDF.

That is your first error. Yes, you must supply a string to `pdf.write` – but only of each separate item you want to write, not the entire input object.

The second is assuming `pdf.write` outputs a line including a *return* at the end. It does not:

> This method prints text from the current position. When the right margin is reached (or the \n character is met), a line break occurs and text continues from the left margin. Upon method exit, the current position is left just at the end of the text.
>   (https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/write/index.html)

You can use  [`ln`](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ln/index.html) to insert line breaks, or append `\n` at the end of each string just before writing it.

Working code:

```
import fpdf

data=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

pdf = fpdf.FPDF(format='letter')
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)

for i in data:
    pdf.write(5,str(i))
    pdf.ln()
pdf.output("testings.pdf")
```