# Add text to existing PDF document in Python

Tags: python, pdf-generation, imagemagick

<strike>I'm trying to convert a pdf to the same size as my pdf which is an A4 page.</strike>

```
convert my_pdf.pdf -density 300x300 -page A4 my_png.png
```

The resulting png file, however, is 595px × 842px which should be the resolution at 72 dpi.
I was thinking of using PIL to write some text on some of the pdf fields and convert it back to PDF. But currently the image is coming out wrong.

Edit: I was approaching the problem from the wrong angle. The correct approach didn't include imagemagick at all.

Comment: You're converting a text file to an image file to write text to it to convert back to a hybrid image / text format? There is __no way__ that's the best way to annotate a `.pdf` or fill out a `.pdf` form.

Comment: You are probably right. I cannot seem to find a proper way to modify an existing pdf in python :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add text to Existing PDF using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at [Add text to Existing PDF using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python) and also [Python as PDF Editing and Processing Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122545/python-as-pdf-editing-and-processing-framework). These will point you in the right direction.

If you do what you've proposed in the question, when you export back to `.pdf`, it will really just be an image file embedded in a `.pdf`, it won't be text.

Comment: i accepted your answer as you made me reread that post(first link) and that led to the solution. Thank you.

Comment: I +1'd you because now I've got a known-working script for when I need to do this myself :)

Answer (score 34):

After searching around some I finally found the solution:
It turns out that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python) was the correct approach after all.
Yet, i feel that it wasn't verbose enough. 
It appears that the poster probably took it from [here](http://language.dyndns.org/research/python/pythonMyScript.htm) (same variable names etc).

The idea: create new blank PDF with Reportlab which only contains a text string.
Then merge/add it as a watermark using pyPdf.

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import StringIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
packet = StringIO.StringIO()
# create a new PDF with Reportlab
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
can.drawString(100,100, "Hello world")
can.save()

#move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
# read your existing PDF
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(file("mypdf.pdf", "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
# add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)
# finally, write "output" to a real file
outputStream = file("/home/joe/newpdf.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: This solution is old and needs corrections. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573258/writing-text-over-a-pdf-in-python3 for corrections

Answer (score 13):

I just tried the solution above, but I had quite some troubles to get it running in Python3. So, I would like to share my modifications. The adapted code looks as follows:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

packet = io.BytesIO()

# create a new PDF with Reportlab
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
can.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world")
can.save()

# move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
# read your existing PDF
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("mypdf.pdf", "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
# add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page2 = new_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(page2)
output.addPage(page)
# finally, write "output" to a real file
outputStream = open("newpdf.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Now the page.mergePage throws an error. Turns out to be a porting error in pypdf2. Please refer to this question for the solution: [Porting to Python3: PyPDF2 mergePage() gives TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974409/porting-to-python3-pypdf2-mergepage-gives-typeerror)

Answer (score 2):

pdfrw will let you take existing PDFs and place them as form XObjects (similar to images) on a reportlab canvas.  There are some examples for this in the pdfrw examples/rl1 subdirectory on github.  Disclaimer -- I am the pdfrw author.