# PYPDF watermarking returns error

Tags: python-2.7, pypdf

hi im trying to watermark a pdf fileusing pypdf2 though i get this error i cant figure out what goes wrong.

i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(0))   File "C:\Python27\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1594, in mergePage
    self._mergePage(page2)   File "C:\Python27\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1651, in _mergePage
    page2Content, rename, self.pdf)   File "C:Python27\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1547, in
_contentStreamRename
    op = operands[i] KeyError: 0
```

using python 2.7.6 with pypdf2 1.19 on windows 32bit.
hopefully someone can tell me what i do wrong.

my python file:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

output = PdfFileWriter()
input = PdfFileReader(open("test.pdf", "rb"))
watermark = PdfFileReader(open("watermark.pdf", "rb"))

# print how many pages input1 has:
print("test.pdf has %d pages." % input.getNumPages())
print("watermark.pdf has %d pages." % watermark.getNumPages())

# add page 0 from input, but first add a watermark from another PDF:
page = input.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)

# finally, write "output" to document-output.pdf
outputStream = file("outputs.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing to a StringIO object instead of a disk file. So, replace this:

```
outputStream = file("outputs.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

with this:

```
outputStream = StringIO.StringIO()
output.write(outputStream) #write merged output to the StringIO object
outputStream.close()
```

If above code works, then you might be having file writing permission issues. For reference, look at the PyPDF [working example in my article](https://www.prahladyeri.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-generate-pdf-in-python-for-google-app-engine.html).

Comment: Thanks Prahlad, that solved some. I figured out the program was having some issues with the watermark file. after re-pdfing the watermark file and changing the permissions it works like a charm.

Comment: Updating broken link of the working example https://www.prahladyeri.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-generate-pdf-in-python-for-google-app-engine.html

Comment: @JulioTrecenti, Thanks for the efforts! Actually I migrated the blog from Openshift wordpress to github-pages a while ago since its free and there are no transfer caps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when attempting to use `PyPDF2` to merge in a page which had been generated by [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), which used an inline image `canvas.drawInlineImage(...)`, which stores the image in the object stream of the PDF.  Other PDFs that use a similar technique for images might be affected in the same way -- effectively, the content stream of the PDF has a data object thrown into it where `PyPDF2` doesn't expect it.

If you're able to, a solution can be to re-generate the source pdf, but to not use inline content-stream-stored images -- e.g. generate with `canvas.drawImage(...)` in reportlab.

Here's an [issue about this](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/196) on PyPDF2.