# How to append text in pdf files using reportlab

Tags: reportlab, pdflib

I need to append some text data in existing `pdf file` using `reportlab`.
Is it possible to do that?
if yes,please provide me a solution.

Comment: Might already have been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python

Comment: Welcome To Stack Overflow. The expectation of those who ask questions here is that they have done some basic research beforehand. While I don't doubt that you have, as you have discovered the `reportlab` package, it's important to show us what else you have tried so time is not wasted duplicating what you've done already