# CssParser Error, while converting html to pdf ,PISA & Python

Tags: python, pdf-generation, pisa, css-parsing

Im trying to convert html documents into pdf file using pisa and python. It works fine for small html code. But when you pass google.com's html data through it , or in fact any big html file , it troughs this error.

here is the code that converts the html to pdf:

```
import ho.pisa as pisa
import sys
import os
ls =[]
for arg in sys.argv:
    ls.append(arg)
pisa.showLogging()
print ls

html_file = open(ls[1])
HTML = html_file.read()
filename = os.path.basename(str(ls[1]))
print filename
str(os.getcwd()+filename)
pdfFile =open(str(os.getcwd()+filename), "wb")
pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(HTML,pdfFile)

if not pdf.err:
    print "ds"
    pisa.startViewer(filename)

pdfFile.close()
html_file.close()
```

and this the error that is thrown :

```
ERROR [ho.pisa] C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\pisa3\pisa_document.py line 223: Document error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\pisa3\pisa_document.py", line 128, in pisaDocument
    c = pisaStory(src, path, link_callback, debug, default_css, xhtml, encoding,
 c=c, xml_output=xml_output)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\pisa3\pisa_document.py", line 73, in pisaStory
    pisaParser(src, c, default_css, xhtml, encoding, xml_output)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\pisa3\pisa_parser.py", line 626, in pisaParser
    c.parseCSS()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\pisa3\pisa_context.py", line 545, in parseCSS
    self.css = self.cssParser.parse(self.cssText)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 358, in parse
    src, stylesheet = self._parseStylesheet(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 453, in _parseStylesheet
    src, atResults = self._parseAtKeyword(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 577, in _parseAtKeyword
    src, result = self._parseAtIdent(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 722, in _parseAtIdent
    src, stylesheet = self._parseStylesheet(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 458, in _parseStylesheet
    src, ruleset = self._parseRuleset(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 737, in _parseRuleset
    src, properties = self._parseDeclarationGroup(src.lstrip())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 922, in _parseDeclarationGroup
    raise self.ParseError('Declaration group closing \'}\' not found', src, ctxsrc)
CSSParseError: Declaration group closing '}' not found:: (u'{', u'0%{opacity:0}50%{opa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trypdf.py", line 16, in <module>
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(HTML,pdfFile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\pisa3\pisa_document.py", line 128, in pisaDocument
    c = pisaStory(src, path, link_callback, debug, default_css, xhtml, encoding,
 c=c, xml_output=xml_output)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\pisa3\pisa_document.py", line 73, in pisaStory
pisaParser(src, c, default_css, xhtml, encoding, xml_output)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\pisa3\pisa_parser.py", line 626, in pisaParser
    c.parseCSS()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\pisa3\pisa_context.py", line 545, in parseCSS
self.css = self.cssParser.parse(self.cssText)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 358, in parse
src, stylesheet = self._parseStylesheet(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 453, in _parseStylesheet
    src, atResults = self._parseAtKeyword(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 577, in _parseAtKeyword
    src, result = self._parseAtIdent(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 722, in _parseAtIdent
    src, stylesheet = self._parseStylesheet(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 458, in _parseStylesheet
    src, ruleset = self._parseRuleset(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 737, in _parseRuleset
    src, properties = self._parseDeclarationGroup(src.lstrip())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sx\w3c\cssParser.py", line 922, in _parseDeclarationGroup
    raise self.ParseError('Declaration group closing \'}\' not found', src, ctxsrc)
sx.w3c.cssParser.CSSParseError: Declaration group closing '}' not found:: (u'{', u'0%{opacity:0}50%{opa')
```

Answer (score 1):

`xhmlt2pdf` is not going to work with all the websites. Instead, you can use [pdfkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit/0.4.1):

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
```

**Edit:**
I've found another solution with PyQt (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359083/how-to-convert-webpage-into-pdf-by-using-python/23761093#23761093), thanks to Mark K):

```
import sys 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import * 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.yahoo.com"))
printer = QPrinter()
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("fileOK.pdf")

def convertIt():
    web.print_(printer)
    print "Pdf generated"
    QApplication.exit()

QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertIt)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does it convert HTML and CSS ?

Comment: @thecreator232 Yes, it converts.