# WKHTMLTOPDF options

Tags: python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf

I can run the following comand under Win cmd box:

```
"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --header-html "C:\temp\Header.html" http://google.de "C:/temp/out_new1.pdf"
```

Output looks like expected and includes the Header.html

However, if I try to place it in Python it will return errors.
I've tryed the following configruration:

```
path_wkthmltopdf = "'C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe' --header-html 'C:/temp/Header.html'"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
```

I'm receiving the following error:

OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "'C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe' --header-html 'C:/temp/Header.html'"

Can u help please?

Thank you very much in advance

Andreas

Comment: binary path only, shold not add option strings: `pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673870/cant-create-pdf-using-python-pdfkit-error-no-wkhtmltopdf-executable-found

Comment: How and where do I define than the options?

Comment: like this `pdfkit.from_url(..., options=options)`, you should read doc first.

Comment: Hi @
I am a Python developer, and I am beginner at using wkhtmltopdf, and currently I have a html being converted into a pdf. But I want to automatically include a table of contents. The documentation says I should put a file called toc.xsl into the param toc. But I am not familiar with .xsl files, so I am not sure what that file should contain. I looked online for examples, but I think they are a little beyond me. Can you please help guide me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the tips.
I figured out how it works.

I try somesing like:

```
path_wkthmltopdf = r"'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe' options=pdf_options"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
```

which is not working.

You have to put the option to the call like

```
pdfkit.from_string(data, outputfile_name, configuration=config, options=pdf_options)
```

Best regards
Andreas

Comment: for me it is worked without the options like this r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'