# pisa.CreatePDF hangs with huge html file

Tags: python, django, pdf, pisa

I am generating pdf using html template with python `pisa.CreatePDF` API,
It works well with small html, but in case of huge html it takes lot of time. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: @NorthCat is there a way to auto generate a table of contents including page numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I did few changes in html which results pisa.createPDF works fast for me.
I am using html of almost **2 MB**, contains single table with almost more than **10,000 rows**. So I break them into multiple tables and tried again. Its surprised me, initially with single table it took almost **40 minutes (2590 seconds)** to generate **PDF** and with multiple tables it has taken only **80 Seconds**.

Comment: Can you please share more details on breaking tables into multiple? Did you create multiple pdf and merged or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pdfkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit):

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.pdf')
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23359083/3489230) which describes solutions using PyQt.

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatically generate a table of contents with the page numbers?