# python cgi html pdf

Tags: python, html, pdf, cgi

I am writing a python CGI script that parses a csv file line by line and creates a HTML table using jinja2. Ideally, each individual HTML instance (one for each line) will get saved as a PDF report.

I've done a lot of searching, and I haven't been able to find a good way to go from HTML to PDF using python. Is it possible to render CGI to PDF? What methods would you recommend to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've done a lot of searching then I am sure you have seen all of the really complicated options for converting html to pdf: ReportLab, weasyprint, pdfkit, etc: as catalogued in this post: [How to convert webpage into pdf using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359083/how-to-convert-webpage-into-pdf-by-using-python).

However, I literally just spent the last month working on the Jinja2 -> HTML -> PDF workflow, so hopefully something of my solution can help you. I found downloading wkhtmltopdf (a small command line program written in C - it's pretty great) and using it from `subprocess` be *by far* the easiest way to accomplish this task. My sample below:

```
import os
import jinja2
import subprocess

def render(template_path, context):
    # Context = jinja context dictionary 
    path, filename = os.path.split(template_path)
    return jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(path or './')
                             ).get_template(filename
                                           ).render(context)

def create_pdf(custom_data, template_path, out_dir, context, keep_html=False):
    # Custom data = the part of my workflow that won't matter to you
    report_name = os.path.join(out_dir, custom_data + "_report")
    html_name = report_name + ".html"
    pdf_name = report_name + ".pdf"

    def write_html():
        with open(html_name, 'w') as f:
            html = render(template_path, context)
            f.write(html)
    write_html()

    args = '"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --zoom 0.75 -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 {} {}'.format(html_name, pdf_name)
    child = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # Wait for the sub-process to terminate (communicate) then find out the
    # status code
    output, errors = child.communicate()
    if child.returncode or errors:
        # Change this to a log message
        print "ERROR: PDF conversion failed. Subprocess exit status {}".format(
        child.returncode)
    if not keep_html:
        # Try block only to avoid raising an error if you've already moved
        # or deleted the html
        try:
            os.remove(html_name)
        except OSError:
            pass
```

Most of this code is well-explained by the documentation for `jinja2` and `subprocess` so I won't laboriously go over it here. The arg flags in wkhtmltopdf translate to Zoom = 75% and 0 width margins (the -B, -L, etc are short hand for bottom, left, etc). The [wkhtmltopdf documention](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) is also quite good.

**Edited:** Credit for the `render` function goes to [Matthias Eisen](https://web.archive.org/web/20170503202707/http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0198/). Usage:

> Assuming a template at /some/path/my_tpl.html, containing:
>
> Hello {{ firstname }} {{ lastname }}!

```
context = {
    'firstname': 'John',
    'lastname': 'Doe'
}
result = render('/some/path/my_tpl.html', context)

print(result)
```

> Hello John Doe!

Comment: Thanks @HFBrowning. I have one question. How do you pass the context? I can't find this rendering technique in the jinja2 documentation. I'm used to rendering like:\n
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
print(template.render(ID = ACCESSION_ID, DATE = date.today()) so I'm not sure how you rendered your "context" variable if you are rendering multiple things. If you could point me to the documentation for html = render(template_path, context), that would be great!

Comment: Edited to show the origin and use of that function - good question. There are lots of code snippets out there demonstrating wildly different strategies for using `jinja2`

Comment: And if it's not clear (not sure how familiar you are with Python), context is a dictionary. My workflow includes saving many (~50) elements to that dictionary, e.g., `context["DATE"] = datetime.datetime.now()`, etc