# Is it possible to convert a html file containing a JavaScript chart to PDF in python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, pdf

I am trying to convert a html file to pdf in python.
The html file has a javascript chart.
 At first, I used weasyprint and pdfkit modules but I found that the modules does not support javascript. 

So now I am using wkhtmltopdf module. It convert most of the html code to pdf, except javascript. Is it possible to convert an html file containing a JavaScript chart to PDF in python?

or should I use another module?

Below is the JavaScript code that does not appear in the pdf file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

FusionCharts.ready(function(){

  var fusioncharts = new FusionCharts({

  type: 'hlineargauge',

  renderAt: 'chart_container',

  width: '350px',

  height: '170px',

  dataFormat: 'json',

  dataSource: {

      "chart": {

          "theme": "fint",

          "caption": "Chart A",

          "lowerLimit": "0",

          "upperLimit": "20",

          "chartBottomMargin": "40",

          "valueFontSize": "11",

          "valueFontBold": "z0"

      },

      "colorRange": {

          "color": [{

              "minValue": "0",

              "maxValue": "11.5",

              "label": "Low",

              "code" : "#FDB881",

          }, {

              "minValue": "11.5",

              "maxValue": "12.5",

              "label": "Typical",

              "code" : "#F18B36",

          }, {

              "minValue": "12.5",

              "maxValue": "20",

              "label": "High",

              "code" : "#D2660D",

          }]

      },

      "pointers": {

          "pointer": [{

              "value": "8",

              'borderColor':'#333333',

              'borderThickness':'3',

              'borderAlpha':'100',

              'bgColor':'#FF0000'
          }]
      },
  }
}
);
  fusioncharts.render();
});
</script>
```

wkhtmltopdf version is 0.12.4 and the command is

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 5000 test.html test.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example from a previous StackOverflow question. 
[How to convert webpage into PDF by using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359083/how-to-convert-webpage-into-pdf-by-using-python)

This example uses the library [pfdkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit/0.4.1)

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
```

If it doesn't render the chart you could try using an iFrame with pdfkit to get desired results!

Here is an example using [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org/)
First, install weasyprint.

```
pip install weasyprint
```

Then run example

```
python
>>> pdf = weasyprint.HTML('http://www.google.com').write_pdf()
>>> len(pdf)
92059
>>> file('google.pdf', 'w').write(pdf)
```

Here is a third example, because i'm fun. :)

```
import sys 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import * 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.yahoo.com"))
printer = QPrinter()
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("fileOK.pdf")

def convertIt():
    web.print_(printer)
    print "Pdf generated"
    QApplication.exit()

QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertIt)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you Steven. Actually the websites is rendered well but I don't know why my javascript chart in a html file is not rendered.

Comment: Maybe try using $(function() { }); so it's rendered when the page loads ? Maybe it's running the script before loading all of it ?

Comment: Not working even after wrapping it in  $(function() { }); 
 any suggestions @BingbongKim

Comment: WeasyPrint doesn't execute JavaScript. [See the issue](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/755#issuecomment-447935386)