# Convert a .pdf/html weblink to pdf document using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert a weblink to pdf. Can anyone please advise if there is a way to do this using python?

```
Sample links(not an actual link) that I need to convert to pdf as below:
```

https://mylink.pdf

https://www.mylink.htm

Comment: You should look at this question's answer. This might be the thing you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359083/how-to-convert-webpage-into-pdf-by-using-python

Comment: Does using a service like [PDFShift](https://pdfshift.io) would work? [Check the Python examples](https://pdfshift.io/features?lang=python).