# Is it possible to save an HTML page as PDF using Python?

Tags: python, html, pdf

I'm trying to create a button which saves an HTML page in PDF format using Python. Are there any libraries which do that? If so, how would you write it up?

The HTML page I'm building contains school information such as name, url, city, state, zip, number of students, etc.

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/23359083/7570485

Comment: Oh hey, thanks. I only saw a JavaScript one. Not a question for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/)?

It is easy to use as well -

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.pdf')
```