# Downloading a pdf based webpage as pdf using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, web

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359083/how-to-convert-webpage-into-pdf-by-using-python) is given a method to download a webpage as pdf, which works.

However, the website I am interested in is also displaying a pdf itself, so this method does not work. For example, [this](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/showPdf.jsf;jsessionid=03B8AD93D8D1B1FBB33A15FDA3774709?text=&docid=62809&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=2874259) page. Is there anything specific for such url's?

When I use the post I shared above, I get the following error:

```
OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Loading pages (1/6)
Error: Failed loading page http://curia.europa.eu/juris/showPdf.jsf;jsessionid=CAE85693A88870E357F61ED4344FD7E9?text=&docid=62809&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=2878455 (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more-or-less basic use of the requests package will help you out here. (This is only slightly fancy with chunking the result.)

```
import requests
outpath = './out.pdf'
url = r"""http://curia.europa.eu/juris/showPdf.jsf;jsessionid=03B8AD93D8D1B1FBB33A15FDA3774709?text=&docid=62809&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=2874259"""
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(outpath, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
            f.write(chunk)
```

For more fun with requests, see: https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/

Comment: Yes, and it works really fast! I iterated over 200 pages like in a minute. Thanks!