# Microsoft Azure Fundamentals Pdf version

Tags: azure

Is there a way I can get a pdf version of this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/azure-fundamentals/, instead of going page after page in the website

Answer (score 0):

you can automate a crawler + html to pdf.

```
pip install weasyprint  # No longer supports Python 2.x.

python
>>> pdf = weasyprint.HTML('http://www.google.com').write_pdf()
>>> len(pdf)
92059
>>> file('google.pdf', 'wb').write(pdf)
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34438445/1384539