# How to Convert HTML Pages to Pdf in Ubuntu using Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pdf

I am trying to figure out how to convert and download an html page to pdf with python on a headless ubuntu server. I have tried using wkhtmltopdf/pdfkit and none of the versions work that I have tried (including using a static version, rather than the ubuntu repository version since that has reduced functionality).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert webpage into PDF by using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359083/how-to-convert-webpage-into-pdf-by-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WeasyPrint

Install:

```
pip install weasyprint
```

Code:

```py
import weasyprint
pdf = weasyprint.HTML('http://www.google.com').write_pdf()
open('google.pdf', 'wb').write(pdf)
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34438445/13710015

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to set the output path?

Comment: @decoy24601 i think you just replace 'google.pdf' with whatever you want