# Using pdfrw and ReportLab to add text to an existing PDF and insert

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab, pdfrw

I want to use pdfrw and ReportLab to:

1. open an existing PDf and add a line of text to it based on x and y coordinates (via ReportLab - drawCentredString(x,y,string)
2. insert the resulting pdf into my report.

So far, here's what I've tried as a modified version of code from [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/07/a-quick-intro-to-pdfrw/):

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader
from pdfrw.buildxobj import pagexobj
from pdfrw.toreportlab import makerl
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

folder='Documents/Assets/'
x = PdfReader(folder+'/'+'BACK_PAGE.pdf',decompress=False).pages
y = pagexobj(x)
c = canvas.Canvas(folder+'/'+'BACK_PAGE_out.pdf')
c.doForm(makerl(c, y))
c.showPage() 
c.save()
```

This is just to open the pdf and save it as a new one (baby steps). 
The problem is, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'inheritable'
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

P.S. I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python), but it is old and I can't get the solutions to work.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurred because:

```
y = pagexobj(x)
```

needed to be:

```
y = pagexobj(x[0])
```

instead (so as not to be a list, as the error implies).