# Collect in online form and automatically fill out PDF forms

Tags: pdf

I am completely new to this forum and basically know nothing about programming.

I am looking for a way to collect data such as personal information (name, address, DOB) in an online form builder (Zoho Forms, Google Forms etc.) and use it to automatically fill out official government issued pdf forms.

I am assisting non-native speakers coming to Germany with their bureaucracy and want to give them the chance to fill out the forms in a language they understand. Because of that, I'd like an online form in English language that creates data to autofill the  official German PDF so the immigrants can just print the filled out German form and send them to the authorities.

In my research I stumbled upon these 2 posts:

[Add text to Existing PDF using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfjinja/1.0.0

Unfortunately they go way over my head and I have problems following the instructions. Furthermore, a more competent friend of mine told me that this would only help to populate the pdf once you have the data collected. What I am looking for is an automatic solution for the whole process from information collection to filled out pdf.

I discovered that Zumeforms http://www.zumeforms.com/document-automation/ offers such solution, but 500 Euros per month is way over my budget. Also, I found a way to collect the information in CSV format, manually convert that to xml and sync the xml with the pdf form, but it's very time consuming.

Do you guys maybe know a solution for my problem?

Best,
Jay

Comment: You've over complicated the problem. Rather than use an online solution, you could easily add some JavaScript to the German language PDF that pops open a dialog to collect the information in English and push the results into the fields. The users would need to use Adobe Reader or equivalent though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't think that the majority of users have Adobe Reader, so that might not solve the problem. Do you know of a solution that would work without Adobe?

Comment: There are literally thousands of combinations of libraries and tools that could work. If you're new to programming and are not familiar with PDF internals, I suggest you hire someone to do this.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it!