# PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger only writes first pdf

Tags: python, pypdf

I have several Pdfs that I want to merge together. To do this I referenced this https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileMerger.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger.write Documentation as well as this [Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files) post as reference.
My code reads from the the directory where my pdfs lie and tries to write the new pdf into another directory

```py
    def concatenate_pdfs(path_to_pdf_dir, output_dir):
        """merge all the pdfs that lie in output_dir into one pdf and store it in path_to_pdf_dir"""
        merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
        for filepath in glob(f'{output_dir}*.pdf'):
            merger.append(filepath)
        merger.write(f'{path_to_pdf_dir}/output.pdf')
        merger.close()
```

The new pdf is created but only with the first pdf that gets parsed.

The same problem occurs when I do it like this:

```py
def concatenate_pdfs(path_to_pdf_dir, output_dir):
    """merge all the pdfs that lie in output_dir into one pdf and store it in path_to_pdf_dir"""
    merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
    f1 = 'path_to_first_pdf'
    f2 = 'path_to_second_pdf'
    f3 = 'path_to_nth_pdf'
    merger.append(f1)
    merger.append(f2)
    merger.append(f3)
    merger.write(f'{path_to_pdf_dir}/output.pdf')
    merger.close()
```

In this case only f1 gets written to my output.pdf

Comment: Does the bug persist if you do ```merger.append(open(fx, 'rb'))```?

Comment: @Tobi208 yes it does. Same result

Comment: Wait. No this solved it. Now they get shown as expected. I had a type while trying your fix. Thank you

Comment: Awesome! The file reader/writer in PyPDF can be a bit iffy.

Comment: Yes, seems like it! Something somewhat unrelated: Do you - by coincidence -  know how to add a title before each new concatenated Pdf? I was able to add the bookmarks but not the title

Comment: Do you mean title in the metadata or a title page before each merge or a title at the top of the page?

Comment: A title at the top of the page before each new merged pdf. F.e.:

Merged pdf 1 title:
content of merged pdf 1

Merged pdf 2 title:
content of merged pdf 2

Comment: Obviously with a new line after the title and - if possible - with a bigger font size.

Comment: You might want to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python). Don't think you can do it with a merger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity:

Add files to the merger with `merger.append(open(filepath, 'rb'))` because PyPDF has some odd internal issues with file reader/writers.