# Add webpage hyperlink to Existing PDF using Python

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, pypdf

I want to add some extra text with external webpage hyperlink to an existing PDF using Python, what is the best way to go about this.

[This code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python#answer-43565052) is just adding text to pdf but not hyperlink.

Below code add link but it's regenerate new pdf -

```python
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, PageBreak, SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

pdf = SimpleDocTemplate('example.pdf')
story = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
story.append(Paragraph('This <a href="http://google.com/" color="blue">is a link to</a>', style=styles["Normal"]))
pdf.build(story)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`writer.add_uri(...)`](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfWriter.html#PyPDF2.PdfWriter.add_uri):

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()

for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)

# Make a black rectangle in the bottom-left corner with the link
writer.add_uri(
    pagenum=0,
    uri="https://martin-thoma.com/",
    rect=(10, 10, 100, 50)
)

with open("out.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```