# how do I turn a content into a stream in pdfs?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I need to make a pdf editor using PyPDF2. but sadly, there are around 4-6 videos around this module and they all show how to edit and manipulate the general screen, not the pdf. so i used the documentation on it's own in order to learn how to use it. i was able to do most stuff with the documentation alone, but once i reached the point of editing text, i couldn't find any way to do so.

here is my current try of editing a pdf's content:

```
import PyPDF2

pdf_file = open('pdf name goes here', 'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
# Get the page that you want to modify
page = pdf_reader.pages[0]

content_object = page["/Contents"].get_object()
content = content_object.get_data()

modified_content = content + b"\n(new text)"

new_content_object = # i don't know how to create the new content object ):

page.__setitem__("/Contents", new_content_object)

pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
pdf_writer.addPage(page)
with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as pdf_output:
    pdf_writer.write(pdf_output)
```

as you can see, my issue is that i don't know how to create a new content object. however, if anybody could suggest me a python module to edit text, i would be very happy. thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can just put new text into an object like that in the first place...

Comment: Anyway, PyPDF2 seems to be the wrong tool anyway: calling `set_data` says "Creating EncodedStreamObject is not currently supported"...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Canvas object from `reportlab` to add text and merge afterwards the two pdf's. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python) it is explained how to do it. Or [here](https://thinkinfi.com/pdf-redaction-using-python/?utm_content=cmp-true) they use fpdf to replace the text in your file.

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.

Many PDF libraries out there simply don't make it easy to add content to a PDF. PDF is not an easy format, and most libraries simply pass that difficulty on to the user.

Such as:

- forcing you to calculate specific coordinates for content
- having you manipulate content streams directly
- not automatically breaking text

If you can change the tool you're working with, try using `borb`.

```
pip install borb
```

and then you can do something like:

```py
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnlayout
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import PDF

# create an empty Document
doc = Document()

# add an empty Page
page = Page()
doc.add_page(page)

# use a PageLayout to be able to automatically add
# content whilst taking into account margin, previous content
# on the page, etc
layout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

# add a Paragraph
layout.add(Paragraph("Hello there!"))

# add a second Paragraph
layout.add(Paragraph("This content is going to be added neatly beneath the first paragraph."))

# store the PDF
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
    PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)
```

You can find more documentation in the [(examples) GitHub repository](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples).