# Placing texts on a pdf(photo of form) using python

Tags: python

I'm making a python program where i use tkinter to make a form for admission, the entries from the user is then place in python variables, I want to to place those entries on a pdf(the pdf is a scanned photo of the physical form), I want to map them to the respective fields on the pdf, Is this even possible? I have been doing research for a week now but nothing seems to work. If anyone could help it would be great.

I tried using the various pdf libraries in python but they dont seem to work in my situation as the pdf is an image of the form.

Comment: I have no experience working with pdfs in Python, but I believe that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17538003/2221001) may be valuable. If I understand correctly, they are creating a new pdf adding text at a specific location, then using `pypdf2` to merge the newly created pdf over the top of the existing pdf. You just have to figure out the x,y coordinates of the text you want to place.